# Set value to false if value if == false

Tags: php

How do I set a value false if the value I set is == false.

I know can I do it like this:

```
$string = ('something that returns true' ? 'something that returns true' : false);
```

But I want something smarter.

I'm looking for something like this.

```
$string = ('something that returns true') ? false;
```

Examples I want to be false:

```
$string = array() ? false;
$string = '' ? false;
```

tl;dr: If the string I'm settings is not == true, set to false.

Comment: you could use `isset()`, `empty()`, `is_null()`. here is a breakdown https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/

Comment: That would be the long solution. I was looking for a really quick shorthand and @AlienWebguy posted that.

Comment: So basically, it's not smarter that you were looking for. It was shorter. There's kind of a difference between the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using 5.3+

```
$string = ('something that returns true') ?: false;
```

Comment: I'm just providing the syntax he asked for.

Comment: Never mind, as I am not sure what the OP wants if the value doesn't evaluate to `false`, your solution is probably a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something, but assuming that you want a boolean value, you just need:

```
$string = (bool) 'something that returns true';
```

This will cast your `array`, `string`, `number` or whatever to a boolean value.